# Mega ADK connecting to PS3 Controller - OSC did not start error

Tags: arduino-mega, usb

I have a project that I am working on that uses a PS3 controller to connect to an Arduino Mega 2560 ADK (built-in USB).  I have been trying to test the controller/arduino connection and I cannot get past the "OSC did not start" error via serial monitor.

I started a new thread because all of the threads I read were based on the Mega 2560 plus the USB shield, not the ADK. Theoretically, there should be no difference, but rather safe than sorry.

Here is my hardware:
Arduino Mega 2560 ADK - Controller
TrendNet TWB-106UB - USB dongle
PS3 Move Navigation Controller (only 1)

Libraries:
USB_Host_Shield
USB_Host_Shield_Library_2.0

Sketch:
https://gitlab.com/darren-blum/SHADOW

However, for the sake of testing, I have tried the straight example sketches from the USB Host libraries.  I have tried the PS3USB and the PS3BT examples.  It does not matter what sketch I try, I cannot get past the "OSC did not start".

The code that triggers this error is:

```
if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nOSC did not start"));
    while (1); //halt
  }
```

I am not sure what I am missing.  Here is one of the example sketches in its entirety:

```
#include <PS3BT.h>
#include <usbhub.h>

// Satisfy the IDE, which needs to see the include statment in the ino too.
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#endif
#include <SPI.h>

USB Usb;
//USBHub Hub1(&Usb); // Some dongles have a hub inside

BTD Btd(&Usb); // You have to create the Bluetooth Dongle instance like so
/* You can create the instance of the class in two ways */
PS3BT PS3(&Btd); // This will just create the instance
//PS3BT PS3(&Btd, 0x00, 0x15, 0x83, 0x3D, 0x0A, 0x57); // This will also     store the bluetooth address - this can be obtained from the dongle when running     the sketch

bool printTemperature, printAngle;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
#if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
  while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
#endif
  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nOSC did not start"));
    while (1); //halt
  }
  Serial.print(F("\r\nPS3 Bluetooth Library Started"));
}
void loop() {
  Usb.Task();

  if (PS3.PS3Connected || PS3.PS3NavigationConnected) {
    if (PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatX) > 137 || PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatX) < 117 || PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) > 137 || PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) < 117 || PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX) > 137 || PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX) < 117 || PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatY) > 137 || PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatY) < 117) {
      Serial.print(F("\r\nLeftHatX: "));
      Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatX));
      Serial.print(F("\tLeftHatY: "));
      Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY));
      if (PS3.PS3Connected) { // The Navigation controller only have one     joystick
        Serial.print(F("\tRightHatX: "));
        Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX));
        Serial.print(F("\tRightHatY: "));
        Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatY));
      }
    }

    // Analog button values can be read from almost all buttons
    if (PS3.getAnalogButton(L2) || PS3.getAnalogButton(R2)) {
      Serial.print(F("\r\nL2: "));
      Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogButton(L2));
      if (PS3.PS3Connected) {
        Serial.print(F("\tR2: "));
        Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogButton(R2));
      }
    }

    if (PS3.getButtonClick(PS)) {
      Serial.print(F("\r\nPS"));
      PS3.disconnect();
    }
    else {
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(TRIANGLE)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nTraingle"));
        PS3.setRumbleOn(RumbleLow);
      }
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(CIRCLE)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nCircle"));
        PS3.setRumbleOn(RumbleHigh);
      }
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(CROSS))
        Serial.print(F("\r\nCross"));
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(SQUARE))
        Serial.print(F("\r\nSquare"));

      if (PS3.getButtonClick(UP)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nUp"));
        if (PS3.PS3Connected) {
          PS3.setLedOff();
          PS3.setLedOn(LED4);
        }
      }
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(RIGHT)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nRight"));
        if (PS3.PS3Connected) {
          PS3.setLedOff();
          PS3.setLedOn(LED1);
        }
      }
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(DOWN)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nDown"));
        if (PS3.PS3Connected) {
          PS3.setLedOff();
          PS3.setLedOn(LED2);
        }
      }
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(LEFT)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nLeft"));
    if (PS3.PS3Connected) {
      PS3.setLedOff();
      PS3.setLedOn(LED3);
    }
  }

  if (PS3.getButtonClick(L1))
    Serial.print(F("\r\nL1"));
  if (PS3.getButtonClick(L3))
    Serial.print(F("\r\nL3"));
  if (PS3.getButtonClick(R1))
    Serial.print(F("\r\nR1"));
  if (PS3.getButtonClick(R3))
    Serial.print(F("\r\nR3"));

  if (PS3.getButtonClick(SELECT)) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nSelect - "));
    PS3.printStatusString();
  }
  if (PS3.getButtonClick(START)) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nStart"));
    printAngle = !printAngle;
  }
}
#if 0 // Set this to 1 in order to see the angle of the controller
    if (printAngle) {
      Serial.print(F("\r\nPitch: "));
      Serial.print(PS3.getAngle(Pitch));
      Serial.print(F("\tRoll: "));
      Serial.print(PS3.getAngle(Roll));
    }
#endif
  }
#if 0 // Set this to 1 in order to enable support for the Playstation Move controller
  else if (PS3.PS3MoveConnected) {
    if (PS3.getAnalogButton(T)) {
      Serial.print(F("\r\nT: "));
      Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogButton(T));
    }
    if (PS3.getButtonClick(PS)) {
      Serial.print(F("\r\nPS"));
      PS3.disconnect();
    }
    else {
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(SELECT)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nSelect"));
        printTemperature = !printTemperature;
      }
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(START)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nStart"));
        printAngle = !printAngle;
      }
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(TRIANGLE)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nTriangle"));
        PS3.moveSetBulb(Red);
      }
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(CIRCLE)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nCircle"));
        PS3.moveSetBulb(Green);
      }
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(SQUARE)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nSquare"));
        PS3.moveSetBulb(Blue);
      }
      if (PS3.getButtonClick(CROSS)) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nCross"));
        PS3.moveSetBulb(Yellow);
  }
  if (PS3.getButtonClick(MOVE)) {
    PS3.moveSetBulb(Off);
    Serial.print(F("\r\nMove"));
    Serial.print(F(" - "));
    PS3.printStatusString();
  }
}
if (printAngle) {
  Serial.print(F("\r\nPitch: "));
  Serial.print(PS3.getAngle(Pitch));
  Serial.print(F("\tRoll: "));
  Serial.print(PS3.getAngle(Roll));
}
else if (printTemperature) {
  Serial.print(F("\r\nTemperature: "));
  Serial.print(PS3.getTemperature());
}
  }
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Idiot me.  I thought Mega 2560 = ADK.  It does not.  Once I corrected my board from the Mega 2560 to the ADK, the USB port worked.

Comment: It's OK to accept your own answer as the solution to the problem.